# How to retrieve a form using AJAX, JSON and PHP onchange of value in a select box?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, calendar

I Have a select box, on selectinga value in it I have to display a form in which there is a Date field which include a javascript calendar functionalty. I tried it with normal AJAX and PHP combination, but I dont get the Calendar in it, So I just need to know How I can make it happen using JSON and AJAX and PHP?

Thanks

Every Help Is Appreciated....

**THE CODE**

This is The Javascript I am Using to AJAX function:

```
<script>
function Inint_AJAX() {
try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");  } catch(e) {} //IE
try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } catch(e) {} //IE
try { return new XMLHttpRequest();          } catch(e) {} //Native Javascript
alert("XMLHttpRequest not supported");
return null;
};
function dochange(path,val) {
var req = Inint_AJAX();
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
 if (req.readyState==4) {
      if (req.status==200) {
            document.getElementById('docfields').innerHTML="";
            if(req.responseText != ''){
           document.getElementById('docfields').innerHTML=req.responseText; //retuen value
            }else{
            document.getElementById('docfields').innerHTML="<br>&nbsp;\t<font size='2'><b>No Fields Available</b></font>";
            }
      }
 }
};
req.open("GET", path+"getDocFields.php?doctype_id="+val); //make connection
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=iso-8859-1"); // set Header
req.send(null); //send value
}
</script>
```

Below Is the HTML form which I need to display with Calendar object (tcal) instantiated in the script tag:

```
<form onsubmit="" action="" method="post" name="newdoc">
         <table border="0" style="border: medium none;" id="docfield">
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="border-right: medium none;">
                Date
            </td>
         <td style="border-right: medium none;">
            <input type="text" value="" maxlength="10" name="Test" style="width: 100px;" id="date">
        <script>
         new tcal ({  
      'formname': 'newdoc',  
      'controlname': 'Test'
         });
     </script>
        </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
</form>
```

I am not getting the calendar displayed...

Comment: have you considered putting some code you already tried? (with more information it is more likely that people will be able to help)

Comment: @Thariama Questiona ahas been edited pls have a look

Comment: what does the ajax request return? (if you do not know use firebug)

Comment: Its returns the HTML format of form fields which needs to displayed in my webpage, I Get the script along with Date input field displyed iun the response but do not get the Date calender icon displayed to use its functionality

Comment: @Thariama, did you got what I am asking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see javascrip in the response html, which will never be executed if the html is coming through ajax call.
Try to put that javascript

```
new tcal ({
'formname': 'newdoc',
'controlname': 'Test'
});
```

after your XMLHttpRequest object fetches and puts data in '#docfields'.

```
if (req.readyState==4)
{
   if (req.status==200)
   {
      document.getElementById('docfields').innerHTML="";
      if(req.responseText != '')
      {
          document.getElementById('docfields').innerHTML=req.responseText; //retuen value
          /** here **/
          new tcal ({'formname': 'newdoc','controlname': 'Test'});
          /** here **/
      }
      else
      {
          document.getElementById('docfields').innerHTML="No Fields Available";
      }
   }
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I just hit this via Google after searching for something similar :) Funny thing, every time I hit SO from a search, I end up editing something.

Answer (score 2):

Imran is right. You need to extract the scriptcode and run it.
This code can be used very commonly:

```
var scripts = "";
$('form)'.find("script").each(function() {
            var content = $(this).html();
            content = content.replace(/<!--/g, "").replace(/(\/\/)?-->/g, "");
            scripts += content;
        });
eval (scripts); // eval is evil, but in this case...
```